# plyr polyfilled, Module parse failed with babel and webpack

Tags: webpack, babeljs, plyr

i have an issue while compiling with symfony/webpack-encore when i upgrade the plyr video player library.

Symfony version : 4.3

a snippet from my package.json file:

```
"devDependencies": {
"@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.20.1",
"babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
"babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"cypress": "^3.0.3",
"eslint": "^5.3.0",
"eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
"eslint-plugin-node": "^7.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.8.0",
"eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.1.0",
"favicons-webpack-plugin": "^0.0.9",
"node-sass": "^4.14.1",
"sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
"svg-sprite-loader": "^3.9.2",
"svgo": "^1.0.5",
"svgo-loader": "^2.1.0"
},
"dependencies": {
"@flowjs/flow.js": "github:flowjs/flow.js",
"abortcontroller-polyfill": "^1.3.0",
"atob": "^2.1.2",
"detect-browser": "^4.5.1",
"fetch-loader": "^1.0.60",
"gsap": "^2.0.1",
"intersection-observer": "^0.5.1",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"mapbox-gl": "^0.51.0",
"outdatedbrowser": "^1.1.5",
"plyr": "^3.6.8",
"select2": "4.0.5",
"select2-bootstrap-theme": "^0.1.0-beta.10",
"sticky-js": "^1.2.0",
"whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0"
},
```

My .babelrc file:

```
{
"presets": [
  [
    "babel-preset-env",
    {
      "useBuiltIns": "usage"
    }
  ]
],
"plugins": [
  "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
  "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread",
  "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"
]
}
```

The issue occurs when updating plyr video library https://github.com/sampotts/plyr from 3.6.4 to 3.6.5 or above with the following error when i launch npm run ./node_modules/.bin/encore production:

```
> ERROR in ./node_modules/plyr/dist/plyr.polyfilled.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4532:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     const event = new CustomEvent(type, {
|       bubbles,
|       detail: { ...detail,
|         plyr: this
|       }
```

The unexpected token refers to the line 'detail: { ...detail'. It's a spread syntax and the plugin babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread is activated. I don't understand why the syntax is not accepted when compiling.
I know that symfony webpack encore and some dependencies are outdated but i can't do a code migration now.

Comment: Sounds like a bug that `plyr` should fix. Have you filed an issue for them? Most likely this isn't working because Babel isn't running on `node_modules` (which is usually the suggestion since compiling all node_modules is much slower). You can probably change the Webpack config to compiling everything as a short-term fix, but you should at least tell them about the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I have added a babel-loader for plyr.polyfilled.js specifically in my webpack and it was ok.